# Zoom arranged ggplot2 in shiny R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, gridextra

I want to zoom a plot based on brushed ranges from `plotOutput()` function in shiny. This is clearly illustrated [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html). However, I have a plot that consists of multiple ggplot plots arranged with gridExtra package, and the trick here appears to not work anymore. It seems that the values of brushed return something like grid values...but I don't know how to map the brushed area with the original data to make the zoom. You can see the problem [here](https://duranferrerm.shinyapps.io/Zoom_shiny_grobs/) and the code is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo) 
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Plot1. Simple ggplot (Brush and double-click to zoom). WORKS!"),
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 300,
                      dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE,direction = "x"
                        ),
                      hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot1_hover",delay = 0)
                      ),
           h5("Plot 1 values hover. Correspond with the data on the plot."),
           verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "values1"),
           h5("Plot 2 values hover. Do not correspond"),
           verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "values2"),
           h5("Plot 3 values hover. When falling in the area, correspond."),
           verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "values3")
           ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Plot2. Arrange 2 ggplots. (Brush and double-click to zoom). DO NOT WORK.."),
           plotOutput("plot2", height = 600,
                      dblclick = "plot2_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot2_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE,direction = "x"
                      ),
                      hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot2_hover",delay = 0)
                      )
           ),
    column(width = 4, class = "well",
           h4("Plot3. Arrange 2 base plots. (Brush and double-click to zoom). PARTIALLY WORK.."),
           plotOutput("plot3", height = 600,
                      dblclick = "plot3_dblclick",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot3_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE,direction = "x"
                      ),
                      hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot3_hover",delay = 0)
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Plot1. Single ggplot
  rangesPlots <- reactiveValues(x1 = NULL,x2=NULL,x3=NULL)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb,mpg)) +
      geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,8,0.25),expand = c(0.015,0))+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = rangesPlots$x1, ylim = rangesPlots$y1) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))
    p
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot1_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      rangesPlots$x1 <- c(brush$xmin,brush$xmax)
    } else {
      rangesPlots$x1 <- NULL
    }
  })
  output$values1 <- renderPrint({
    paste0("x=",input$plot1_hover$x," y=",input$plot1_hover$y)
  },width = 100)

  # Plot2. Multiple ggplot2
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb,mpg)) +
      geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,8,0.25),expand = c(0.015,0))+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = rangesPlots$x2) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))
    p2 <- arrangeGrob(p,p,heights = c(0.4,0.6))
    grid.draw(p2)
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot2_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot2_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      rangesPlots$x2 <- c(brush$xmin,brush$xmax)
    } else {
      rangesPlots$x2 <- NULL
    }
  })
  output$values2 <- renderPrint({
    paste0("x=",input$plot2_hover$x," y=",input$plot2_hover$y)
  },width = 100)

  # Plot3 Base plot
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    plot(mtcars$carb,mtcars$mpg,xaxt="n",xlim=rangesPlots$x3)
    text(x=seq(0,8,0.25)[-c(1:4)],y=par()$usr[3]-0.3,labels = seq(0,8,0.25)[-c(1:4)], srt=45, adj=1, xpd=TRUE)
    plot(mtcars$carb,mtcars$mpg,xaxt="n",xlim=rangesPlots$x3)
    text(x=seq(0,8,0.25)[-c(1:4)],y=par()$usr[3]-0.3,labels = seq(0,8,0.25)[-c(1:4)], srt=45, adj=1, xpd=TRUE)
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot3_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot3_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      rangesPlots$x3 <- c(brush$xmin,brush$xmax)
    } else {
      rangesPlots$x3 <- NULL
    }
  })
  output$values3 <- renderPrint({
    paste0("x=",input$plot3_hover$x," y=",input$plot3_hover$y)
  },width = 100)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```